# What is the name of this connector (on a Fuji GX680)?

Tags: connector

I have a Fuji GX680 (I) camera; it has a remote shutter connector. Buying a remoter shutter control second hand is quite expensive. So I am wanting to fabricate my own. Unfortunately I am unable to work out what the specific connector socket is (so I can buy the correct plug).

The connector has :

1. 8 Pins, evenly spaced in a circle
2. 3 orientation lugs, 1 large 2 small
3. 10mm outer diameter
4. A stylized logo of the letters HRS

---

[image: Fiji GX680 Remote Control connector socket, with centimeter scale ruler to show scale]

Comment: HRS is Hirose but their website seems painful for this kind of search.   You may do better asking on a camera forum since you'll presumably need the wiring/signal details, too, and if that is known the connector presumably is as well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have the wiring diagram so that is Ok. I am just looking for the part number so I can order it off Element 14 or wherever.

Comment: If you can't find what connector it is, it could be a custom connector, made and sold only for Fuji, according to their specifications. So it might not be available anywhere.

Comment: @Justme Having spent last night searching through their catalog. I am beginning to think that may be the case. As a plan B I am trying to work out how I would make a dental like impression of the camera and then fabricate some thing. Maybe I should take up ChrisStratton's idea and post on Photography SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your question only now, but here is the datasheet. If you need more info on the GX680 III vs the I/II and their remote releases, let me know. [Google Drive link to datasheet for the GX680 remote release connector](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_bV2ctyzISYFfpOeoP-bZ3xlQ6mxCiwj/view?usp=sharing)

Alternate links to the datasheet for those Hirose RP6 series plastic connectors: https://www.digikey.cn/htmldatasheets/production/69814/0/0/1/rp6-series.html

https://pdf.dzsc.com/RP6/RP6-SC-212.pdf

Comment: Great find on the connector.

Comment: Thanks @GTElectronics ! The III-version of the remote release is hard to find... I am trying to get hold of one. I'd like to modify a I/II version, that's why I dived into the pinout and the connector type. Anyone here knowing how to modify the wiring to make it work without draining the camera batteries real fast? Thanks.